# I need a character or string which will match ANY value in my table field

Tags: php, mysql, pattern-matching

I have a form that requires the user to only fill out at least 1 (out of four) fields. They can then submit and get a search result based off of their input.

The problem is, I can't get a character to set my variables to that will match any database value. Here is my code for some context;

```
   if (isset($_POST['buildname']) ||
    isset($_POST['weapon']) ||
    isset($_POST['category']) ||
    isset($_POST['id']))

{
if ($_POST['buildname'] == "") 
    {
        $buildname = ".*";
    }
if ($_POST['weapon'] == "")
    {
        $weapon = ".*";
    }
if ($_POST['category'] == "")
    {
        $category = ".*";
    }
if ($_POST['id'] == "")
    {
        $id = ".*";
    }


$buildname  = sanitizeString($_POST['buildname']);
$weapon     = ($_POST['weapon']);
$category   = ($_POST['category']);
$id         = ($_POST['id']);

$searchstring = "SELECT buildname,weapon,category,id,author FROM weapons " .
                "WHERE buildname='$buildname' AND weapon='$weapon' AND category='$category' AND id='$id'";
```

As you can see, the code looks at if one of the variables is set, then submits a form. If a variable isn't set, it assigns a character of ".*" (which I thought would match anything). It then queries the database to match any rows. I get no results unless I enter EVERY field with a correct entry.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: improve your code writing :/

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `%`, instead do something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['buildname']) || isset($_POST['weapon']) || isset($_POST['category']) || isset($_POST['id'])){

    $sqlArray = array();

    if(isset($_POST['buildname'])){
        $sqlArray[] = "buildname='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['buildname']) . "'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['weapon'])){
        $sqlArray[] = "weapon='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['weapon']) . "'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['category'])){
        $sqlArray[] = "category='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['category']) . "'";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $sqlArray[] = "id='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['id']) . "'";
    }

    $searchstring = "SELECT buildname,weapon,category,id,author FROM weapons " .
                    "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $sqlArray);

}
```

Comment: Awesome, this one worked perfectly. Had to fix it up a bit to work with my coding but it was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard character for MySQL is: %

Answer (score 0):

No, you are using `=` operator, that only compares 2 values. In your case it will search for '.*' - and fail. If you want to ignore the fields, that were not filled, just don't put them into the query: no need for regexps. So, if the weapon and category are missing, your query should be like this

```
$searchstring = 'SELECT buildname,weapon,category,id,author FROM weapons WHERE ';

$fields = array('buildname', 'weapon', 'category', 'id');
$data = array();
foreach($fields as $value)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$value]) && ($_POST[$value] != "") )
    {
        $data[] = sanitizeString($_POST[$value]);
    }
}

$n = count($data);
if($n > 0)
{
    $searchstring .= implode(' AND ', $data);
    //do MySQL request and output result
}
```

Don't overcomplicate simple things. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection as some fields are not escaped.

Comment: Thanks -- the ones I didn't escape are dropdown fields so I assumed you couldn't inject into them.

But the query you provided -- what if the user wants to refine the search by entering the category? Then it is not included in the query

I want the user to be able to enter any one, two, three or four of the four fields, and get a result.

Comment: @user2628338 You must check, whether the user entered the data and add the appropriate conditions into the query. The user can create a malicious request, so escape everything.

Answer (score 0):

The query you are executing, you "thought would match anything" wont. The statement uses no regular expressions.

`WHERE buildname='$buildname' AND weapon='$weapon'`

Which is essentially saying you need to have the following fields equal their string value of:

`WHERE buildname='.*' AND weapon='.*'`

I doubt you have any building with a name of `.*`.

It would be better to not filter on that field. basically remove the `WHERE` cause criteria if the variable is not defined.

You can do this dynamically, buliding the SQL statement only when you need to filter by that field.

```
if (isset($_POST['somevalue']) && ! empty($_POST['somevalue'])) { 
  $where .= 'column_name = ?';
  $values[] = sanitizeString($_POST['somevalue]);
}
```

I've also used `positional parameters` which assumes you will be using the `PDO` or `MySQLi` libraries for querying.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$fields = array('buildname', 'weapon', 'category', 'id');

$sql = 'SELECT buildname, weapon, category, id, author FROM weapons';
$prefix = ' WHERE ';
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field]) && strlen($_POST[$field])>1) {
        $sql .= $prefix . $field . '=\''
             . sanitizeString($_POST[$field]) . '\'';
        $prefix = ' AND ';
    }
}

if ($prefix == ' AND ') {
// send the query
}
```

Notice: if you want to perform search with incomplete values, you could use `LIKE` instead of `=`, example:

```
$sql .= $prefix . $field . ' LIKE \'%' . sanitizeString($_POST[$field]) . '%\'';
```

But keep in mind that `LIKE` is slower than `=`